# I want to output as a pure csv but it output with HTML tags

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I updated the code, but getting some tags before the data

```
<br />                                              
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-warning' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>                                             
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span>
```

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare()    called in
>   C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\sinetiks-schools\deped_rpci.php
>   on line 14 and defined in C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php
>   on line *1246*

```
</th></tr>                                          
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>                                             
<tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>                                              
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0000</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>312032</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-admin\admin.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\admin.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>                                               
<tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>2</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.0010</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>331856</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>require_once( <font color='#00bb00'>'C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-load.php'</font> )</td><td title='C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-admin\admin.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>..\admin.php<b>:</b>31</td></tr>
```

here's the code

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['exp'])) {

$wpdb->show_errors(); 

 global $wpdb;

 // Grab any post values you sent with your submit function
 $DownloadReportFrom = "ReportDateFrom";
 $DownloadReportTo = "ReportDateFrom";

 // Build your query                        
 $MyQuery = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM wp_rpci_rpci'));


 // Process report request
 if (! $MyQuery) {
  $Error = $wpdb->print_error();
   die("The following error was found: $Error");
  } else {
 // Prepare our csv download

 // Set header row values
 $csv_fields=array();
 $csv_fields[] = 'Field Name 1';
 $csv_fields[] = 'Field Name 2';
 $csv_fields[] = 'Field Name 1';
 $csv_fields[] = 'Field Name 2';
 $csv_fields[] = 'Field Name 1';
 $csv_fields[] = 'Field Name 2';
 $output_filename = 'MyReport_' . $DownloadReportFrom .'-'.   $DownloadReportTo  . '.csv';
 $output_handle = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

 header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
 header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
  header( 'Content-type: text/csv' );
 header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $output_filename );
 header( 'Expires: 0' );
 header( 'Pragma: public' );    

 // Insert header row
 fputcsv( $output_handle, $csv_fields );

 // Parse results to csv format
 foreach ($MyQuery as $Result) {
$leadArray = (array) $Result; // Cast the Object to an array
// Add row to file
fputcsv( $output_handle, $leadArray );
}

// Close output file stream
fclose( $output_handle ); 

die();
exit();
}
 }
?>
```

i get some table then it display the database rows after the table tags

Comment: What output did you get ? and what you want to be fixed, I mean please clear your issue

Comment: it outputs the HTML tags but not the table content

Answer (score 0):

You don't use mysqli_query but wpdb::query.

As [wpdb::query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/query/) returns number of rows affected/select, you pass the integer into mysqli_fetch_assoc and it fails for obvious reason as it expects mysqli_result instead of some number.

You need to get real mysqli connection and then your code will work.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working :)

I just eliminate redundant argument

Heres the code

```
$wpdb->show_errors(); 
global $wpdb;                       
// Grab any post values you sent with your submit function
$DownloadReportFrom = "ReportDateFrom";
$DownloadReportTo = "ReportDateFrom";

// Build your query 
// $MyQuery = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM wp_rpci_rpci')); -Delete the ($wpdb->prepare                 
$MyQuery = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_rpci_rpci');



// Process report request
if (! $MyQuery) {
$Error = $wpdb->print_error();
die("The following error was found: $Error");
} else {
// Prepare our csv download

// Set header row values
$csv_fields=array();
$csv_fields[] = 'Field Name 1';
$csv_fields[] = 'Field Name 2';

$output_filename = 'MyReport_' . $DownloadReportFrom .'-'. $DownloadReportTo  . '.csv';
$output_handle = @fopen( 'php://output', 'w' );

 header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
  header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
 header( 'Content-type: text/csv' );
 header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $output_filename );
header( 'Expires: 0' );
header( 'Pragma: public' ); 

// Insert header row
fputcsv( $output_handle, $csv_fields );

// Parse results to csv format
 foreach ($MyQuery as $Result) {
$leadArray = (array) $Result; // Cast the Object to an array
// Add row to file
fputcsv( $output_handle, $leadArray );
}

// Close output file stream
 fclose( $output_handle ); 

 die();

 }
```